# Let $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{R})$. Suppose that $f''(x) = 0,$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is a polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I'm studying for the entrance exam to the Master's and I came across this analysis question, from one of the previous exams. The exam will ask you real analysis questions. I would like to know if my reasoning is correct (I'm studying Real Analysis but I haven't reached the Riemann Integral part yet).

Let $f  \in C^2(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{R})$ and let [a, b] an arbitrary closed interval. We know that $f'$ is continuous in [a, b] and derivable in (a, b). By the Mean Value Theorem, we have that for every $x \in (a, b]$ exists $c \in (a, x)$ such that

$$0 = f''(c) = \dfrac{f'(x) - f'(a)}{x - a}$$

$$\Rightarrow f'(x) = f'(a).$$

So, we have that $f'$ is a constant in every closed interval [a, b] arbitrary. Therefore, $f'$ is constant in $\mathbb{R}$. It suffices then to integrate $f$, to verify that $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: How do you go from “$f'$ is constant in $\Bbb R$” to “$f$ is polynomial” through the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Yes, I would add that $f$ is affine to be more precise, but this is correct (maybe a bit quick in the end compared to the beginning). You don't need the mean value theorem since you could have used your fundamental theorem on $f'$ and $f''$ (this is a bit overkill). I think you already know that $f'=0$ on an interval implies that $f$ is constant, so apply that to $f'$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry. I must have confused the Theorem. What I was trying to say was that by integrating f' we would get a polynomial.

Comment: Then what about doing it twice in order to solve the original question?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos As I said, I still don't have all the formal knowledge of integrals. That's why I chose not to do that.

Comment: You don't have formal knowledge of integral yet you attend to an entrance exam for a Master? this seems odd

Comment: @JulesBesson The university where I study suffers from a shortage of professors. I took a real analysis course but we got to the derivatives part. I'm redoing everything I studied in analysis to start with the integral part. That's why I said that I don't have all the technical knowledge of integrals. I've already done differential and integral calculus but I don't want to run the risk of coming here on the forum to say wrong things.

Comment: Ok I see, use my first comment then. Or you could use twice the mean value theorem too. A better exercise would be show that $f^{(k)} = 0$ iff $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k-1$.

Comment: @JulesBesson Thanks for the sugestion. I will try to prove it.